# Problem with slanted numerals when combining siunitx and arev

Tags: fonts, math-mode, siunitx, units

There is a strange interaction between the `siunitx` and `arev` packages, whereby all the numerals appear slanted when using commands such as `\num` or `\SI`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{arev}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is is some normal math: \( 1 + 1 = 2\). Looks OK. 
\item This is using the \verb|\num| macro from \texttt{siunitx}: \num{1.23e45}. Why are the numbers slanted? The problem only occurs with the \texttt{arev} font. 
\item It is only the numerals that appear slanted, the units themselves are OK: \SI{20}{km/s}  
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Is there a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening here is that, for sans serif fonts, `siunitx` picks up the change of style at the start of the document and switches to use `\mathsf` in math mode and `\sffamily` in text mode. However, the `arev` font has slanted numerals in its `\mathsf` font, which leads to the weird result you see. If you put

```
\sisetup{math-rm = \mathrm}
```

*after* `\begin{document}` the problem will go away. Alternatively, wait until tomorrow and a fix will be available on CTAN: I'll get it done in a second!

Comment: I don't understand why my `detect-mode=true` solution works, then...

Comment: @Seamus: Because the font is fine in text mode, so your `\num` use is typeset using `\textsf`.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph - the fix works perfectly. I had tried setting `\sisetup{math-rm = \mathrm}` but only in the preamble, where of course it has no effect

Comment: So if you don't `detect-mode=true` all numbers are set with the mathmode font, is that right?

Comment: @Seamus: The standard settings in v2 of `siunitx` use the math font for numbers and the text font for units. (See the `number-mode` and `unit-mode` options.)

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all=true}
\usepackage{arev}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is is some normal math: \( 1 + 1 = 2\). Looks OK. 
\item This is using the \verb|\num| macro from \texttt{siunitx}: \num{1.23e45}. Why are the numbers slanted? The problem only occurs with the \texttt{arev} font. 
\item It is only the numerals that appear slanted, the units themselves are OK: \SI{20}{km/s}  
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The `detect-all=true` option will detect the current mode and font family and use them.

Actually, all you need is `detect-mode=true` which detects whether you're in mathmode or text mode. Strangely though, this will still set things italic if you're in mathmode: `$\SI{20}{\kilo\metre\per\second}$` would still be italic. Weird. I think this is to do with `siunitx`'s assumptions about mathmode default being italic.

Comment: You might want to email Joseph Wright about this. Or wait until he reads this question...